# VIM Rainbow Parenthese autostart

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using the [rainbow_parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim) plugin and I'm wishing for it start on VIM start. Currently, on start-up, nothing changes; when Load_Rainbow is called manually after start-up, it works.

The relevant vimrc section is as follows:

```
" Rainbow Parentheses options {
    function! Config_Rainbow()
        call rainbow_parentheses#load(0)
        call rainbow_parentheses#load(1)
        call rainbow_parentheses#load(2)
    endfunction

    function! Load_Rainbow()
        call rainbow_parentheses#activate()
    endfunction

    augroup TastetheRainbow
        autocmd!
        autocmd Syntax * call Config_Rainbow()
        autocmd VimEnter * call Load_Rainbow()
    augroup END
" }
```

Comment: It appears to work for me. As in when I type parenthesis they are rainbow colored.

Comment: As in, this exact code with this exact plugin works for you? Also, what version and platform of VIM are you running?

Comment: I did a git clone of the repository in the link. Copied the settings into my vimrc. I'm running vim 7.3 patches 1-244, 246-762 on mac os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As checked by FDinoff above, this issue appears to be platform specific: Win 64bit, as tested with the binaries from [here](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/64-bit-vim-builds-for-windows-64-bit/wiki/Home) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/wiki/Win64Binaries). This was confirmed when testing those settings in a 32bit gVim. I'm still unsure of the exact root cause, however I have discovered a work-around. I think the problem is the ordering of the Syntax and VimEnter autocmd events, so the solution is to set the VimEnter autocmd during the Syntax event.

vimrc:

```
" Rainbow Parentheses options {
    function! Config_Rainbow()
        call rainbow_parentheses#load(0) " Load Round brackets
        call rainbow_parentheses#load(1) " Load Square brackets
        call rainbow_parentheses#load(2) " Load Braces
        autocmd! TastetheRainbow VimEnter * call Load_Rainbow() " 64bit Hack - Set VimEnter after syntax load
    endfunction

    function! Load_Rainbow()
        call rainbow_parentheses#activate()
    endfunction

    augroup TastetheRainbow
        autocmd!
        autocmd Syntax * call Config_Rainbow() " Load rainbow_parentheses on syntax load
        autocmd VimEnter * call Load_Rainbow()
    augroup END

    " rainbow_parentheses toggle
    nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :call rainbow_parentheses#toggle()<CR>
" }
```