# Vim plugin : Rainbow parentheses using tab

Tags: vim, plugins, parentheses

I'm using vim 7.3 and Rainbow Parentheses plugin. When opening multiple tabs with `vim -p file1 file2` or with `vim -S session.vim`, or even with `tabnew file` or any other method, my parenthesis are colored in only one file.

I just put this into my .vimrc : `au VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle`
as said [here](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim). I tried to use `:RainbowParenthesesToggle` on the other tabs once opened but it only toggles in the parenthesis-activated tab.

What should I do to make things work in all tabs ?

Comment: What os are you running? The OP of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387463/vim-rainbow-parenthese-autostart) thought the problem was OS related. (or at least how vim was configured on said os)

Comment: If you know where the issue tracker of that plugin is, why don't you simply ask there?

Comment: @FDinoff Running RHEL 4.

Comment: @romainl And actually, I couldn't find any issue tracker for the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by adding the same instructions as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387463/vim-rainbow-parenthese-autostart) in my .vimrc, thanks to FDinoff. I replaced the last instruction to make it work using tab, as I intended first.

```
function! Config_Rainbow()
    call rainbow_parentheses#load(0)
    call rainbow_parentheses#load(1)
    call rainbow_parentheses#load(2)
endfunction

function! Load_Rainbow()
    call rainbow_parentheses#activate()
endfunction

augroup TastetheRainbow
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax * call Config_Rainbow()
    autocmd VimEnter,BufRead,BufWinEnter,BufNewFile * call Load_Rainbow()
augroup END
```

Comment: There is a problem with this technique : it seriously mess with the folding of my C files. Did not found any workaround yet :/

Answer (score 2):

The `VimEnter` flag on the autocommand tells vim to perform the command specified (in this case `RainbowParenthesesToggle` only when starting the editor, which is in your case when you open the first file.

If you want to extend the functionality to everytime you load a buffer you should do something like:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

Comment: Sorry, still not working. Whenever I open a new buffer, RainbowParentheses is still not activated.  
This seems logical as i tried `RPToggle` after opening a new file in tab, which is quite the same as your solution